# How i use the same keypress for 2 variables?(LUA)

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

EXAMPLE: If i press the M6 button, my cursor go to a X place, if i press the M6 button again he goes to a Y place, how can i does this alternation ?

```
local TOPX, TOPY, MIDX, MIDY

TOPX = 59305        -- Top side X
TOPY = 54527        -- Top side Y
MIDX = 61764        -- Mid lane X
MIDY = 58683        -- Mid lane Y

function OnEvent(event, arg)
        for n = 1,2
            do
            if      event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 6 then
                            MoveMouseTo(MIDX, MIDY);
        for n = 2,4
            do  
                if
                    event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 6 then
                            MoveMouseTo(TOPX, TOPY);    

end
end
end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be having an outter flag boolean variable which would allow you to identify the state of the M6 button strokes.

```
local buttonPressedOnce = true

function onEvent(event, arg)
    -- Check if the button is the one we desire.

    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 6) then
        if (buttonPressedOnce) then
            -- execute X update code
        else
            -- execute Y update code
        end

        buttonPressedOnce = not(buttonPressedOnce)
    end
end
```

Explanation: The first press will always be the X axis update code, so we initialize the flag as true, and with each click call we proceed to update the flag value, making sure each button stroke will switch to the desired state.

Comment: Can you do a exemple of button conditional? i don't understand that

Comment: Every click of mouse make the command, don't just the M6